# Apache proxy: Why is one vhost returning Forbidden while the other one works?

Tags: apache-http-server, proxy, ssl, reverse-proxy

I have a Java application that needs to talk to another intranet website using HTTPS in both directions. After fighting with Java's SSL implementations for some time, I gave up on that, and have now set up an Apache that's supposed to act as a bidirectional reverse proxy:

```
external app ---(HTTPS request)---> Apache ---(local HTTP request)---> Java app
```

This direction works just fine, however the other direction does not:

```
Java app ---(local HTTP request)---> Apache ---(HTTPS request)---> external app
```

This is the configuration for the vhost implementing the second proxy:

```
Listen 127.0.0.1:8081

<VirtualHost appgateway:8081>
   ServerName appgateway.local

   SSLProxyEngine on
   ProxyPass        / https://externalapp.corp:443/
   ProxyPassReverse / https://externalapp.corp:443/
   ProxyRequests Off
   AllowEncodedSlashes On

   # we do not need to apply any more restrictions here, because we listened on
   # local connections only in the first place (see the Listen directive above)
   <Proxy https://externalapp.corp:443/*>
      Order deny,allow
      Allow from all
   </Proxy>
</VirtualHost>
```

A `curl http://127.0.0.1:8081/` should serve the equivalent of `https://externalapp.corp`, but instead results in `403 Forbidden`, with the following message in the Apache error log:

```
[Wed Jun 04 08:57:19 2014] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] Directory index forbidden by Options directive: /srv/www/htdocs/
```

This message completely puzzles me: Yes, I have not set up any permissions on the DocumentRoot of this vhost, but everything works fine for the other proxy direction where I haven't. For reference, here's the other vhost:

```
Listen this_vm_hostname:443

<VirtualHost javaapp:443>
   ServerName javaapp.corp

   SSLEngine on
   SSLProxyEngine on
   # not shown: SSLCipherSuite, SSLCertificateFile, SSLCertificateKeyFile
   SSLOptions +StdEnvVars

   ProxyPass        / http://localhost:8080/
   ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost:8080/
   ProxyRequests Off
   AllowEncodedSlashes On

   # Local reverse proxy authorization override
   <Proxy http://localhost:8080/*>
      Order deny,allow
      Allow from all
   </Proxy>
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: Have you configured the external app's firewalls and/or the "homegroup" (or its equivalent)?  I just recently had a networking issue which was solved by both tweaking the firewall and by ensuring the homegroup was set correctly.

Comment: What Apache version do you have?

Comment: The Apache version is 2.2.12-1.30.1 (SLES package). Will try to find someone who can check the firewall settings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the problem. It's the `<VirtualHost>` statement:

```
<VirtualHost appgateway:8081> # broken
<VirtualHost *:8081>          # works
```

Because of the wrong VirtualHost specification, the HTTP requests did not match the virtual host. As no host was applicable, the default host configuration was used, which doesn't have a valid `DocumentRoot`, thus a Forbidden message was shown.

The other virtual host worked "accidentally" because its name matches the hostname of the machine.